# Kendo Notification in Code Behind

Tags: kendo-ui, notifications, code-behind

I have searched and didn't find any solution for my problem. My problem is that I couldn't call notification from my controller and all notification codes are related about razor or js or inside html. I have to write from .cs file and my cs file like that;

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Kullanici model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.KullaniciAdi))
            {
                // 
            }

            KullaniciDAL kullanicidal = new KullaniciDAL();
            Kullanici kullanici = kullanicidal.GetRowByKullaniciAdi(model.KullaniciAdi);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kullanici.KullaniciAdi))
            {
                // 
            }

            string s = Code.Dev.Crypto.Decrypt(kullanici.Sifre);
            if (s == model.Sifre)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CustId", kullanici.CustId);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                cookie = new HttpCookie("KullaniciAdi", kullanici.KullaniciAdi);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                cookie = new HttpCookie("KullaniciRol", "Uzman");
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                //notification will be showed
                //Kendo.Mvc.UI.NotificationTemplate notification = new Kendo.Mvc.UI.NotificationTemplate();
                //notification
                return View("Login");
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's server side. You could do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899393/kendo-ui-notifications-and-mvc

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Take a look at this article. We use a similar approach to provide notifications from MVC. http://www.toplinestrategies.com/blogs/net/standardizing-aspnet-mvc-feedback-toastr